# No fields in scala class are set when returned from query

Tags: scala, orientdb

I have a Scala class, User:

```
class User {
   @OId var id: String = _

   var email: String = _

   var password_hash: String = _
   var password_salt: String = _

   var admin : Boolean = _

   @OVersion var version: String = _
}
```

I can successfully create and store User objects in the DB, but when I query for a User, e.g. db.queryBySql[User]("select * from User where email = ?", username)

I get a User object back, but all fields are null.

When stepping the code I can see the correct result from the DB, the POJO conversions is what fails.

I am using scala 2.9.2 and Orient DB 1.1.0.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I thought it might be due to Scala-generated getters and setters, but after discussing with Fredrik and looking at http://code.google.com/p/orient/wiki/Object2RecordJavaBinding#Getters_and_Setters I don't think this is the case. Adding the @BeanProperty annotation didn't help, so deleting my answer.

Comment: I have also tried with the exact same code as in the link above, and I get the same result. Will check OrientDB on Google groups.

Answer (score 0):

I did the exemple explain at : http://code.google.com/p/orient/wiki/ScalaLanguage
This exemple uses the local connexion

```
var db: ODatabaseObjectTx = new ODatabaseObjectTx("local:/tmp/dbtmp")
```

I change a little the main app.
I change import to match with organisation of OrientDb packages.

```
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.id.ORecordId
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.query.OSQLSynchQuery
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.`object`.ODatabaseObject
import com.orientechnologies.orient.`object`.db.ODatabaseObjectTx
```

And, I change the way to open connexion. 
Be careful ODatabaseObjectTx is deprecated.
I use db2 instead db after this snippet.

```
var db2:ODatabaseObject =
if (!db.exists) {
  db.create()
} else {
  db.open("admin", "admin")
}
```

I import these packages :

```
orient-commons:1.1.0
orientdb-core:1.1.0
orientdb-object:1.1.0
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:1.0.0.Final
scala-library:2.9.2
```